# Impact of kernel on system call

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, system-calls, cpu-usage

I have two different machines:

Machine 1:

**# uname**

Linux

**# uname -r**

2.6.34.15-WR4.3.fp_x86_64_standard-00239-g7934205

Machine 2:

**# uname**

Linux

**# uname -r**

4.4.217-pc64-distro.git-v2.102-3-rc

A process "X" is having higher CPU in Machine 2 than in machine 1.

Process X is  having exactly same code on both these machines. The load on the process is also same.

The question here is system calls being used here can have different CPU impacts as the kernel is different in both these machines?

P.S: Machine 2 is having some customization in OS as well.

Is there any way to check CPU usage by system call?
Oprofile not running on this machine..  May be not installed. Don't have permission to install the same.

Any other tool that can help?

Also Please can anyone help in letting me know if TCP SEND AND RECV buff have any impact on the CPU of a process?

Comment: What do you mean by "CPU impact"? Anywhere, in the different kernel versions system calls have (most likely) a different code. So executing this code definitely puts CPU into different conditions.

Comment: By CPU impact I mean the load on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, yes. The CPU load of a process is comprised of its user space processing (i.e. the process code), and its kernel space (a.k.a "system", i.e. time spent in system calls). Because the system call implementation may have changed in between kernels, it is possible that this led to more processing in kernel space.

But there's a longer answer , and it would depend on which system calls these are, and whether it's the direct system call implementation, or a change in a kernel subsystem (e.g. I/O scheduler?), as well as those customizations you've mentioned.